# Авторизация на bitbucket.org через Google

Tags: git, bitbucket

Решил завести удаленный репо на `bitbucket.org`, зашел через `google`, создал приватный репо, сгенерил пару ssh-ключей, со своей машины тяну/толкаю без проблем.

На другой машине попытался стянуть по `ssh`, `git` спрашивает пароль...

Какой пароль я должен вводить? Репо приватный, но никакого пароля конкретно на репо я не устанавливал. Когда вхожу на`bitbucket.org` тоже никакого пароля не ввожу, т.к. логинюсь через `google`.

Пароль от google-аккаунта не проходит, это нормально?

Сделал репо публичным, тогда заработало. Но хочу разобраться.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сгенерируйте ssh-ключ и добавьте его в свой аккаунт в bitbucket. Вариант 2: в настройках учетной записи задайте пароль.

Comment: Дело происходит на виртуальном хостинге, ключи отменяются. Понятно, что можно задать пароль в настройках аккаунта.
Просто в чем смысл тогда авторизации через google, если пароль от google-аккаунта не подходит. Это нормально?

Comment: @pavelchervov, я думаю для Вас не секрет что в открытом виде пароли никто не хранит? У гугла по сути нет Вашего пароля. Есть результат вычисления какой-то функции (проще говоря хеш). И отдавать они его никому не будут. Авторизация через гугл происходит по токену. Я бы например, как владелец сайта, все равно генерировал случайный пароль и высылал его на почту. Но битбакет почему то так не делает.

Comment: Да, спасибо, уже убедился, задал пароль в настройках аккаунта на bitbucket.org, и он проходит, когда тяну из репо. Пользы от возможности "зайти через Google" не много, имя пользователя и email прописался и все, остальное руками надо заполнять.